# How to start jboss7.1.1 server in windows 8 64 bit?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

How to start the jboss server ? i have seen documentation says standard.bat and domain.bat. I'm getting confusing , Please advise which .bat to start the server and need to deploy the jbpm project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Edit the `service.bat`. Then go ahead with the following instructions:

1. JBoss includes a batch file named `standalone.bat` (in the bin folder) that will start the JBoss AS. Please ensure that this script will run JBoss as you like.

   Start AlwaysUp.

   Select Application > Add to open the Add Application window

   On the General tab:

   - In the Application field, enter the full path to the standalone.bat 
         file (C:\JBoss\bin\standalone.bat for us).
   - In the Name field, enter the name that you will call the application 
        in AlwaysUp.
   - If the target PC is dedicated to running JBoss, boost the server's priority to ensure that Windows will grant  it the maximum amount of resources on the host PC.

   On the LogOn tab:

   - Enter the user name and password of the account in which you setup JBoss AS.

     If you wish to hide the DOS/command window that comes up when you run JBoss from the batch file (recommended), check the When a user logs on, don't show the application's windows and tray icons (if any) box at the bottom.

   Click over to the Startup tab and check the Ensure that the Windows Networking components have started box. This informs AlwaysUp that JBoss needs the TCP/IP networking stack to operate.

   Click over to the Extras tab. If you wish to capture the text normally displayed on the command window created by standalone.bat (recommended), check the Capture output to this log file box and specify the full path to a file. We have specified C:\JBoss\jboss-log.txt.

   Click the Save >> button. In a couple of seconds, an application called JBoss will show up in the AlwaysUp window. It is not yet running though.

   To start JBoss, choose Application > Start "JBoss".

That's it you are done!

Ref# [Link](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunJBossAsAService.html)

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, `Standalone.bat` is cases where you don't use clusters. `Domain.bat` in case of clusters.

My guess is, in your case `standalone.bat` should be good enough.